# MYSQL: How to JOIN tables based on id if not found any record then by default value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

> I want to Join two tables based on id or default id.

I've two tables thats storred all countries in different languages:

**country:**

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `ctry_id` smallint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ctry_iso` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ctry_id`)
);
```

**country_lang:**

```
CREATE TABLE `country_lang` (
  `ctryl_ctry_id` smallint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ctryl_lang_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ctryl_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf32_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ctryl_ctry_id`,`ctryl_lang_id`)
) ;
```

$lang_id = 129;

```
SELECT c.ctry_id, cl.ctryl_name,cl.ctryl_lang_id
 FROM country c
 LEFT JOIN country_lang cl on cl.ctryl_ctry_id = c.ctry_id AND ((cl.ctryl_lang_id= $lang_id AND cl.ctryl_lang_id) OR cl.ctryl_lang_id=1)
 ORDER BY c.ctry_iso ASC
```

I just want to get record join by provided lang_id, If no record country record found in country_lang table correspond a lang_id then return by id 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following is more what you are looking for?

```
SELECT c.ctry_id, cl.ctryl_name,cl.ctryl_lang_id, c.ctry_iso, 
       c.ctry_iso3, c.ctry_flag, c.ctry_phone_code
 FROM country c
 LEFT JOIN country_lang cl on cl.ctryl_ctry_id = CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM country_lang WHERE ctryl_ctry_id=ctry_id)
   THEN ctryl_ctry_id
   ELSE 1 END
 ORDER BY c.ctry_iso ASC
```

This will return exactly *one* line per `country`-record and will match *either* the corresponding language id *or* default id `1`.

Or, using `COALESCE()`, you could also write

```
SELECT c.ctry_id, cl.ctryl_name,cl.ctryl_lang_id, c.ctry_iso, 
       c.ctry_iso3, c.ctry_flag, c.ctry_phone_code
 FROM country c
 LEFT JOIN country_lang cl on cl.ctryl_ctry_id = COALESCE( 
   (SELECT ctryl_ctry_id FROM country_lang WHERE ctryl_ctry_id=ctry_id),1)
 ORDER BY c.ctry_iso ASC
```

(Admittedly, I have not yet understood, what special significance your `cl.ctryl_lang_id=129` holds and what behaviour you want if this `ctryl_lang_id` pops up.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT c.ctry_id, cl.ctryl_name,cl.ctryl_lang_id, c.ctry_iso, c.ctry_iso3, c.ctry_flag, c.ctry_phone_code
 FROM country c
 LEFT JOIN country_lang cl on cl.ctryl_ctry_id = c.ctry_id 
where (cl.ctryl_lang_id=129 AND cl.ctryl_lang_id=1)
ORDER BY c.ctry_iso ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, But was return same result.

Comment: @GovindSamrow:- What is the expected result? You have not mentioned that in your question

Comment: I want single result by cl.ctryl_lang_id=129 OR cl.ctryl_lang_id=1 but it was returning both .

Comment: @GovindSamrow:- Then you can simply change the conditon in where clause as `cl.ctryl_lang_id=129 AND cl.ctryl_lang_id=1`

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

SELECT 
c.ctry_id,    cl.ctryl_name,   cl.ctryl_lang_id,       c.ctry_iso,    c.ctry_iso3,    c.ctry_flag,    c.ctry_phone_code
FROM country c
LEFT JOIN country_lang cl
ON cl.ctryl_ctry_id =    c.ctry_id
WHERE IF(EXITS(select * from country_lang     where(country_lang.ctryl_lang_id=129)), cl.ctryl_lang_id=129,    cl.ctryl_lang_id=1)
ORDER BY c.ctry_iso ASC

Comment: what kind of result did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Working for me:

```
SELECT c.ctry_id, cl.ctryl_name,cl.ctryl_lang_id, c.ctry_iso
 FROM `dr4us`.country c
 LEFT JOIN `dr4us`.country_lang cl on cl.ctryl_ctry_id = c.ctry_id AND cl.ctryl_lang_id = CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT icl.ctryl_lang_id FROM country_lang icl WHERE icl.ctryl_ctry_id = c.ctry_id AND icl.ctryl_lang_id = $lang_id)
   THEN $lang_id
   ELSE 1 END
 ORDER BY c.ctry_iso ASC
```